# $\lim\limits_{x\mapsto \infty}\int_0^x| f (x, t)|dt = 0$ implies $\lim\limits_{x\mapsto \infty} f (x, t) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

$\lim\limits_{x\mapsto \infty}\int_0^x |f (x, t)|dt = 0$ implies $\lim\limits_{x\mapsto \infty} f (x, t) = 0$ for all $ t$. $\quad$$ f (x, t) $ is jointly continuous in the variables $ x, t $

$ x \in [0 \quad \infty), t \in R $

Is it true or is there a counter example to the above?

If $ f (x, t)=g (x) h (t) $ $\quad $ then it is true but this is not always the case.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x,t) \to 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$? What domain is $f$ continuous on?

Comment: @flaw. For all $ t $. Domain is $ R $

Comment: So what exact domain should $f$ be continuous on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counter example:

for each integer $n > 0$

$r(t)=-{\frac {n}{t^2-(n-1)^2}}$

$h(t)=-{\frac {n}{n^2-t^2}}$

$\psi_n(t) =
\begin{cases}
e^{r(t)+h(t)},  & \text{if $n-1 <t< n$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$g_n(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $t \in (n-1, n)$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

choose a sequence {$a_n$} such that $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and we have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty|a_n|<\infty$

$$z_n(x,t)=a_n \frac{n^2e^{-n^2(x-nt)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

$$f (x, n)=f(x,0)=0$$

for $t \ne 0$$$f(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-x^2/n^2}\psi_n(t)g_n(t)z_n(x,t)$$

$$\int_{t=0}^\infty |f(x,t)|dt \le e^{-x^2/N^2}\sum_{n=1}^N|a_n|+ \sum_{n=N}^\infty |a_n|<\infty$$

$$ \lim\limits_{x\mapsto \infty}\int_{t=0}^x|f(x,t)|dt \le \lim\limits_{x\mapsto \infty} e^{-x^2/N^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|= 0$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\mapsto \infty} f(x,t)\ne 0$$   since for any large $x$ and $t=n-1/2 \in (n-1, n)$ we can find some large $n$ have  $x=nt$ and $z_n=\frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $\psi_n(t) ->e^{-2}$ so we have $f(x,t)\ge \frac {e^{-3}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 2,$ let $g_n:\mathbb R^2 \to [0,1]$ be continuous with compact support in $B((n,1),1/n^2),$ with $g_n((n,1))=1.$ Note that the balls $B((n,1),1/n^2)$ are pairwise disjoint. Define $f:\mathbb R^2 \to [0,1]$ by setting $f(x,t) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} g_n(x,t).$ Then $f$ is nonnegative and continuous on $\mathbb R^2,$ and

$$\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,t)\,dt\, dx \le \sum_{n=2}^\infty 1\cdot (\pi/n^4) < \infty.$$

If $x\ge n,$ then

$$\int_0^x f(x,t)\,dt \le \frac{2}{n^2}.$$

Thus these integrals $\to 0$ as $x\to \infty.$ Since $f(n,1) = 1$ for all $n,$ we have a counterexample.

Comment: I couldnt understand how you defined $ g_n (x, t) $

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: You haven't defined $g_n(x,t)$ $\quad$ youonly said $g_n((n,1))=1$

Comment: My first sentence says a lot more than $g_n((n,1)) = 1.$ It tells us all we need to know about $g_n.$ There's no use in being more explicit with the definition, because it would be a distraction.

Comment: I simplified your argument.

Comment: That's hardly simpler, but whatever ...

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{t=0}^x\sin(tx)\left( 1 - \frac1{tx}\right) = \frac{1-\cos(x^2) - \mbox{ Si }(x^2)}{x}
$$
So
$$
\lim_x\to\infty\int_{t=0}^x\sin(tx)\left( 1 - \frac1{tx}\right) = 0 $$

Yet 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(tx)\left( 1 - \frac1{tx}\right) $$ does not exist.

Comment: You function is not absolutely integrable over $[0 \quad \infty )$

Comment: @s.t.a.l.k.e.r_2133     You never stated such a requirement.